# Is there likely to be an xpsTeX?

Tags: tex-core

The 2007 TUG April Fools' [announcement](http://tug.org/pipermail/pdftex/2007-April/007112.html) was pretty funny, but does this idea have any traction whatsoever?  From a design point of view, XPS may be the starting point for future document formats beyond PDF (XML-based instead of binary, to my understanding), and is also [internationally standardized](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_XML_Paper_Specification).

I understand XPS itself may not have enough traction as a document format and may not warrant the effort of creating such an engine, but perhaps someone has already written one out of curiosity (or at least something of a dvi2xps).

---

I keep thinking to myself that this may be too soft a question as it stands, so here's a stab at a more concrete one:

> Is the document format of XPS robust enough to handle everything that TeX can offer, especially considering the features we've come to know and love with pdfTeX?
>   Does TeX as an open source project still have the developmental masochism required to write a compiler to XPS?

(As for an 'xpsTeX', I would be satisfied with a `dvips ps2pdf`-like workflow, but obviously direct compilation would be cooler.)

Comment: 1. i wouldn't base anything on ecma's say-so alone; 2. there's an awful lot of investment in pdf that would need to be re-invented; 3. it would be a heck of a big job to do, in itself, let alone the supporting stuff in (2).

Comment: @wasteofspace It admittedly is something of a novelty question; (1) XPS is still a relatively new format (notably, one which ISO has yet to take a look at).  I think XPS is a similar container-y format---this renders (2) as 'not a big deal'.  (3) Well, of course it is!

Comment: I'm really tempted to post an answer of `no` but last time I posted a one word answer I got loads of downvotes:-)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle my first thought: 'someone downvoted David *Carlisle*!?' ***EDIT***: Liar.  You have no downvoted answers.

Comment: 82 downvotes according to http://data.stackexchange.com/tex/query/117308/downvotes-for-a-specific-user  (enter id 1090 for me)

Comment: @DavidCarlisle cool tool; but you still have [no answers in the red](http://tex.stackexchange.com/users/1090/david-carlisle?tab=answers&sort=votes&page=81).

Comment: @SeanAllred that would be negative total I think, not no downvotes my "emacs" answer for example has 10 downvotes but still comes out positive.

Comment: The question is more if it is absolutely necessary. You can already today convert pdf documents to xps documents. I only tried with a few test documents but it seems there is no great difference. So xpsTeX most likely not but pdfTeX to xps works. The feature set is almost identical anyway: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_OpenXPS_and_PDF

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number of successful development projects taking the TeX engine and extending it is pretty small. (There have been a number of unsuccessful or unlikely-to-be-finished projects.) In particular, only pdfTeX has taken Knuth's TeX and altered the output format possible, adding direct PDF production in addition to retaining the ability to create DVI files. Other newer engines have either stuck with (or at least close to) DVI (XeTeX) or have developed from pdfTeX (LuaTeX). Thus from this point of view it looks *highly unlikely* that an engine would be developed offering direct output in another format.

At the same time, it's worth considering why *direct* output would be required. pdfTeX can do some things in PDF mode that cannot be done in DVI mode. However, simply swapping PDF output for XPS output doesn't of itself add anything over using a PDF-to-XPS or DVI-to-XPS converter. There would need to be a *strong* impetus in terms of new functionality to make the production of a new engine output method even worth considering: at present I don't see this.